# How to resolve high priority issue at the time of delivery

Tags: manual-testing, test-management

What will you do if you find a high priority bug and your client wants to deploy the software after knowing that critical bug and you don't have your Developer to fix that bug he is on vacation?

Answer (score 1):

This question may have different answers from various perspective. My opinion is You can explain to the client about the impact of the critical bug on the end user. So that you can delay the release by not losing the brand reputation or find out is there any workaround to fix the bug without developers help.  But the go-live decision needs to be taken by the client.

Still, client wants to move it to live you can defer the particular functionality with the bug to next release with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot technically ***resolve*** it due to time restraint.

- Testing lead has a final say during decision making stage, if it is a blocking issue, a testing lead can recommend against its release.
- If it has to be released, you can at least document it as a known issue; even better, write down any potential work around if there is any.
- I have never personally encountered a situation that a customer wants a piece of software so bad that they are knowingly accepting a buggy release.

Comment: Yes I agree, why client would like to go ahead with critical bug knowingly...

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can have multiple options:

- If the release is so important on that date then disable the module and launch the product. Once the release is over fix the bug, test the entire product and move to Live.
- Keep this issue as a known issue and launch the product. Then later fix it and move to Live.
- Try to find the root cause on which build it has got failed and deploy the previous builds and verify that.
- If the client still wants launch the product on the same date then in such worst case try to contact the developer who is in vacation to get some clarification about that module and work with the alternate developer.